# Pick random names from different lists excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, random

I would like to pick random names from columns in excel like this :

-In the first sheet "Inscrp" is where the lists are, and the second sheet "Tirage" is where the results of the picking.

-Column A in the sheet "Tirage" should pick random names from column A in the sheet "Inscrp" and the same for the column B, C , till the number of columns I chose
I managed to do this with only the first column and here is the code :

```
Sub PickNamesAtRandom()
Dim HowMany As Integer
Dim NoOfNames As Long
Dim RandomNumber As Integer
Dim Names() As String 'Array to store randomly selected names
Dim i As Byte
Dim CellsOut As Long 'Variable to be used when entering names onto worksheet
Dim ArI As Byte 'Variable to increment through array indexes
Application.ScreenUpdating = False

HowMany = 5
CellsOut = 8
ReDim Names(1 To HowMany) 'Set the array size to how many names required
NoOfNames = Application.CountA(Worksheets("Inscrp").Range("A3:A100")) - 1 ' Find how many names in the list
i = 1
Do While i <= HowMany
RandomNo:
    RandomNumber = Application.RandBetween(3, NoOfNames + 1)
    'Check to see if the name has already been picked
    For ArI = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
        If Names(ArI) = Worksheets("Inscrp").Cells(RandomNumber, 1).Value Then
            GoTo RandomNo
        End If
    Next ArI
    Names(i) = Worksheets("Inscrp").Cells(RandomNumber, 1).Value  ' Assign random name to the array
    i = i + 1
Loop
'Loop through the array and enter names onto the worksheet
For ArI = LBound(Names) To UBound(Names)
    Worksheets("Tirage").Cells(CellsOut, 1) = Names(ArI)
    CellsOut = CellsOut + 1
Next ArI

Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Comment: `RandomNumber` may (randomly) return the same name. Should it be OK, or adapt the code to avoid such a case??

Comment: It should avoid getting the same name from the same column

Comment: How, since the names are randomly selected? In order do do that, the already extracted one must be eliminate from the range/array...

Comment: yes since I apply the code the already extracted should be eliminated for sure, but each column should be picked separately for example I have 5 names in column A in the first sheet and  I want to pick to 2 names from there , now other names are in the first sheet in column B should go to column B in the second sheet. 
another point the code that prevent getting the same name is already there so I only need a loop or something to each time random names are picked from a column it goes to the next for both sheets

Comment: Please, try the code I posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, test the next code. If I correctly understand your nee, it will extract `HowMany` random numbers from each column (`nrCol`) of "Inscrip" sheet and placed starting from `CellsOut` in sheet "Tirage". The already extracted name is eliminated from the array where it used to exist (to avoid repeated names). The ranges ar placed in arrays and due to that, the code should be very fast mostly working in memory, even for large ranges:

```
Sub PickNamesAtRandom()
 Dim shI As Worksheet, lastR As Long, shT As Worksheet, HowMany As Long
 Dim rndNumber As Integer, Names() As String, i As Long, CellsOut As Long

 HowMany = 5: CellsOut = 8
 Set shI = Worksheets("Inscrp")
 Set shT = Worksheets("Tirage")

 Dim col As Long, arrCol, filt As String, nrCol As Long
 nrCol = 2 'number of columns to be returned. It can be changed and also be calculated...

 For col = 1 To nrCol
    lastR = shI.cells(shI.rows.count, col).End(xlUp).Row 'last row in column to be processed
    If lastR >= HowMany + 2 Then '+ 2 because the range is build starting with the third row...
        arrCol = Application.Transpose(shI.Range(shI.cells(3, col), shI.cells(lastR, col)).Value2) 'place the range in a 1D array
        
        ReDim Names(1 To HowMany) 'Set the array size to how many names required
        For i = 1 To UBound(Names)
tryAgain:
            Randomize
            rndNumber = Int((UBound(arrCol) - LBound(arrCol) + 1) * Rnd + LBound(arrCol))
            If arrCol(rndNumber) = "" Then GoTo tryAgain
            Names(i) = arrCol(rndNumber)
            filt = arrCol(rndNumber) & "##$$@": arrCol(rndNumber) = filt
            arrCol = filter(arrCol, filt, False)   'eliminate the already used name from the array
        Next i
        shT.cells(CellsOut, col).Resize(UBound(Names), 1).Value2 = Application.Transpose(Names)
    End If
 Next col
 MsgBox "Ready..."
End Sub
```

If something unclear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications...

Comment: Works like magic, Thank you very much. Honestly I need to learn more about VBA Excel

Comment: @youbitto Everybody needs learning... Like I said, if something not clear, do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. I tried commenting only the code lines considering that make the understanding easy...

Comment: oh I noticed that if there are empty cells in the worksheet "Inscrp" it shows an error "9", because not all columns should be filled for example a will only fill the B and C column and not A

Comment: @youbitto Not so clear what you try saying... Are there empty cells in a column or empty columns and you try processing them? Do you mean skipping the first column from iteration? On which code line is the mentioned error raised?

Comment: The error shows here `Names(i) = arrCol(rndNumber)` line 15 , for example I have in "Inscrp" sheet the column A B C D they represent sessions, the A and C sessions are empty "no names"  and B and D are filled, that what I tried to do and got the error.

Comment: @youbitto You did not answer my question... Is it a matter of empty columns? Or "empty cells", as you said before? If empty columns, as I supposed, it makes some sense. Anyhow, both cases can be handled, but you must clearly state where the real problem is...

Comment: yes if there is an empty cell it shows the error too, well if possible empty column should be skipped and empty cell should be skipped as well to the next cell.

Comment: @youbitto I adapted the code to skip the columns having less rows than `HowMany`. In case of an empty cell it should return an empty string, not raising an error... But if you want skipping the empty cells, too, I can adapt the code. Even if I must firstly count the empty cells in order to adapt the case of empty columns, if you understand what I mean... Please, test the adapted code and send some feedback, for now.

Comment: Now it skips the column but the empty cell is considered as a name

Comment: @youbitto Yes, as I said, but no error should be raised... I adapted the code to deal with this issue, too. In case of an empty string it will jump above and return another name. I did not comment the code lines, thinking that they are easy to be understood. If something unclear, please do not hesitate to ask for clarifications. But **you should state in your question all the aspects to be taken in consideration**. We here are not mind readers... :)

Comment: Thank you very much, sorry if I troubled you, I cant express myself very well in english, thank you again ** you are awesome** the code worked very well

Comment: @youbitto  You did not "trouble" me. I like helping people. But more than that, **I like making them learning**! Even the community rules... :)